# asymptotically sharp upper and lower bound for for arctan

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, trigonometry, inequality

How do I prove that $\frac{\pi}{2}-\frac{1}{x}<\arctan(x)<\frac{\pi}{2}-\frac{1}{x}+\frac{1}{3x^3}$ for all $x>0$?

Comment: Have you made an attempt at this or have any ideas in mind?

Answer (score 3):

Hint: $$\dfrac{1}{x^2} \ge \dfrac{d}{dx} \arctan(x) = \dfrac{1}{1+x^2} \ge \ldots$$

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:**

Consider $f(x) = \tan^{-1}x + \frac1x-\frac\pi 2$, show $f'(x)< 0$
and note $\lim_{x\to \infty} f(x) = 0$.

Next consider $g(x) = \frac\pi2 - \frac1x-\tan^{-1}x +\frac1{3x^3}$ along the same lines.

Answer (score 2):

We have
$$
\arctan(1/x)=\frac\pi2-\int_0^x\frac{\mathrm{d}t}{1+t^2}
$$
and
$$
1-t^2\le\frac1{1+t^2}\le1
$$
Therefore,
$$
\frac\pi2-x\le\arctan(1/x)\le\frac\pi2-x+\frac13x^3
$$
and
$$
\frac\pi2-\frac1x\le\arctan(x)\le\frac\pi2-\frac1x+\frac1{3x^3}
$$

Answer (score 0):

use well known indentity
$$\arctan{x}+\arctan{\dfrac{1}{x}}=\dfrac{\pi}{2}$$
so
$$\Longleftrightarrow \dfrac{1}{x}-\dfrac{1}{3x^3}<\arctan{\dfrac{1}{x}}<\dfrac{1}{x}$$
let
$$\dfrac{1}{x}=t$$
then we only prove following inequality
$$t-\dfrac{1}{3}t^3<\arctan{t}<t$$
This is also well know inequality.